# My lambda function results in a timeout when I call multiple AWS services using it for multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am moving my Flask API(s) to Lambda + API Gateway. It requires me to connect with Cognito and RDS in the same lambda function. It works well a couple of times. I provide email and password as request body. Lambda takes these credentials, logs me in to Cognito using boto3 library and returns access token. If authentication is successful, I proceed to get the extra user details using the same email. I get all of them, package them in a dictionary and return from Lambda via API gateway.

This works well for 5-10 times (varies everytime it works) and then stops working (starts to timeout) for an unexplainable amount of time (hours to a day) and then starts to work again for the same code. I do not know why this is happening. I can share more info if you want. But if any of you has experienced throttling(??) of this kind which doesn't really show up as throttled lambda reports but rather lambda stopping to work with other AWS services.

I have tried checking whether all lambda operations cease to stop or not and I found that they don't. Only the ones that involve talking to other aws services with boto3. The weird thing is that everything works seamlessly when boto3 is called from inside an EC2. It timesout after a few successful calls from inside a lambda.

Logs:
4th last line takes all the time (establishing connection). I have tried with both admin_initiate_auth and initiate_auth. Both fail in similar fashion (continuous timeout after a few successful attempts)

```
2022-01-12T00:50:54.991+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:54,990 botocore.utils [DEBUG] IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.169.254/

2022-01-12T00:50:54.991+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:54.991Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53

2022-01-12T00:50:54.993+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:54,991 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53

2022-01-12T00:50:54.993+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:54.993Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search

2022-01-12T00:50:54.994+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:54,993 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search

2022-01-12T00:50:55.011+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:54.994Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Looking for credentials via: env

2022-01-12T00:50:55.011+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:54,994 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: env

2022-01-12T00:50:55.011+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.11Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section

2022-01-12T00:50:55.011+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,011 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section

2022-01-12T00:50:55.014+09:00   [INFO] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.11Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Found credentials in environment variables.

2022-01-12T00:50:55.014+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,011 botocore.credentials [INFO] Found credentials in environment variables.

2022-01-12T00:50:55.014+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.14Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask

2022-01-12T00:50:55.014+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,014 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask

2022-01-12T00:50:55.015+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.15Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section

2022-01-12T00:50:55.015+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,015 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section

2022-01-12T00:50:55.015+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.15Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search

2022-01-12T00:50:55.015+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,015 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search

2022-01-12T00:50:55.015+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,015 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section

2022-01-12T00:50:55.015+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.15Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section

2022-01-12T00:50:55.030+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.30Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/endpoints.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.030+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,030 botocore.loaders [DEBUG] Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/endpoints.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.056+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.56Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/endpoints.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.070+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,056 botocore.loaders [DEBUG] Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/endpoints.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.097+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.96Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f955cea00d0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.110+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,096 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f955cea00d0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.110+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.110Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f955cea00d0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.110+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,110 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f955cea00d0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.315+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.315Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/codeguruprofiler/2019-07-18/service-2.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.315+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,315 botocore.loaders [DEBUG] Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/codeguruprofiler/2019-07-18/service-2.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.330+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.330Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event creating-client-class.codeguruprofiler: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f955cf3ec10>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.332+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,330 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event creating-client-class.codeguruprofiler: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f955cf3ec10>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.332+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.331Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/cognito-idp/2016-04-18/service-2.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.333+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.332Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Creating a regex based endpoint for codeguru-profiler, ap-northeast-1

2022-01-12T00:50:55.333+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,331 botocore.loaders [DEBUG] Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/cognito-idp/2016-04-18/service-2.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.357+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,332 botocore.regions [DEBUG] Creating a regex based endpoint for codeguru-profiler, ap-northeast-1

2022-01-12T00:50:55.371+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.371Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Setting codeguru-profiler timeout as (60, 60)

2022-01-12T00:50:55.372+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,371 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Setting codeguru-profiler timeout as (60, 60)

2022-01-12T00:50:55.391+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.391Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event before-parameter-build.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f955cead550>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.392+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,391 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event before-parameter-build.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f955cead550>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.393+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.392Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event creating-client-class.cognito-identity-provider: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f955cf3ec10>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.393+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,392 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event creating-client-class.cognito-identity-provider: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f955cf3ec10>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.410+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.393Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event before-call.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f955ceb3dc0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.411+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,393 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event before-call.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f955ceb3dc0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.411+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.411Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Setting cognito-idp timeout as (60, 60)

2022-01-12T00:50:55.411+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,411 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Setting cognito-idp timeout as (60, 60)

2022-01-12T00:50:55.412+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.411Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Making request for OperationModel(name=ConfigureAgent) with params: {'url_path': '/profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55'}, 'body': b'{"fleetInstanceId": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:836281999550:function:iws_authenticate", "metadata": {"ComputePlatform": "AWSLambda", "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:836281999550:function:iws_authenticate", "AgentId": "458edeb0-c867-48b5-9e62-551272da93b0", "LambdaMemoryLimitInMB": "512", "ExecutionEnvironment": "AWS_Lambda_python3.9", "AwsRequestId": "a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798", "LambdaRemainingTimeInMilliseconds": "4500"}}', 'url': 'https://codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f955c9f7fd0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}

2022-01-12T00:50:55.412+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,411 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Making request for OperationModel(name=ConfigureAgent) with params: {'url_path': '/profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55'}, 'body': b'{"fleetInstanceId": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:836281999550:function:iws_authenticate", "metadata": {"ComputePlatform": "AWSLambda", "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:836281999550:function:iws_authenticate", "AgentId": "458edeb0-c867-48b5-9e62-551272da93b0", "LambdaMemoryLimitInMB": "512", "ExecutionEnvironment": "AWS_Lambda_python3.9", "AwsRequestId": "a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798", "LambdaRemainingTimeInMilliseconds": "4500"}}', 'url': 'https://codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f955c9f7fd0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}

2022-01-12T00:50:55.412+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.412Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event request-created.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f955c9f7fa0>>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.413+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,412 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event request-created.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f955c9f7fa0>>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.413+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.413Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event choose-signer.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f955cead430>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.413+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,413 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event choose-signer.codeguruprofiler.ConfigureAgent: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f955cead430>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.413+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.413Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/_retry.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.414+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,413 botocore.loaders [DEBUG] Loading JSON file: /var/runtime/botocore/data/_retry.json

2022-01-12T00:50:55.414+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.414Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Calculating signature using v4 auth.

2022-01-12T00:50:55.415+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,414 botocore.auth [DEBUG] Calculating signature using v4 auth.

2022-01-12T00:50:55.415+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.414Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Registering retry handlers for service: cognito-idp

2022-01-12T00:50:55.415+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,414 botocore.client [DEBUG] Registering retry handlers for service: cognito-idp

2022-01-12T00:50:55.415+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.415Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 CanonicalRequest: POST /profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent host:codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com x-amz-date:20220111T155055Z x-amz-security-token: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 host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token 6597adf75fd24a25ec215f3148f1e86f3e04dfd2c2a3cb64fa57d24b7fe70192

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,415 botocore.auth [DEBUG] CanonicalRequest:

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   POST

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   /profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   host:codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   x-amz-date:20220111T155055Z

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   x-amz-security-token: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

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   6597adf75fd24a25ec215f3148f1e86f3e04dfd2c2a3cb64fa57d24b7fe70192

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.416Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 StringToSign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20220111T155055Z 20220111/ap-northeast-1/codeguru-profiler/aws4_request a6d46b3081b0c8cc0c9922f6871b8158b81cb79db2cd29d39138e844858bc0a1

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,416 botocore.auth [DEBUG] StringToSign:

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   20220111T155055Z

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   20220111/ap-northeast-1/codeguru-profiler/aws4_request

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   a6d46b3081b0c8cc0c9922f6871b8158b81cb79db2cd29d39138e844858bc0a1

2022-01-12T00:50:55.416+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.416Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Signature: 1f2b56c6850d65dd451cc554ce801f2460994150aa8ef89b2846876c3e8abf10

2022-01-12T00:50:55.430+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,416 botocore.auth [DEBUG] Signature:

2022-01-12T00:50:55.430+09:00   1f2b56c6850d65dd451cc554ce801f2460994150aa8ef89b2846876c3e8abf10

2022-01-12T00:50:55.430+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.416Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event before-parameter-build.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f955cead550>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.430+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,416 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event before-parameter-build.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f955cead550>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.431+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.430Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent, headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20220111T155055Z', 'X-Amz-Security-Token': b'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', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIA4FNSKUC7MXWAR2GV/20220111/ap-northeast-1/codeguru-profiler/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=1f2b56c6850d65dd451cc554ce801f2460994150aa8ef89b2846876c3e8abf10', 'Content-Length': '462'}>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.431+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,430 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/profilingGroups/aws-lambda-iws_authenticate/configureAgent, headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20220111T155055Z', 'X-Amz-Security-Token': b'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', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIA4FNSKUC7MXWAR2GV/20220111/ap-northeast-1/codeguru-profiler/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=1f2b56c6850d65dd451cc554ce801f2460994150aa8ef89b2846876c3e8abf10', 'Content-Length': '462'}>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.432+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,431 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event before-call.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f955ceb3dc0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.432+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.431Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event before-call.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f955ceb3dc0>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.432+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.432Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Certificate path: /var/runtime/botocore/cacert.pem

2022-01-12T00:50:55.432+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,432 botocore.httpsession [DEBUG] Certificate path: /var/runtime/botocore/cacert.pem

2022-01-12T00:50:55.432+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.432Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Making request for OperationModel(name=InitiateAuth) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'X-Amz-Target': 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55'}, 'body': b'{"AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH", "AuthParameters": {"USERNAME": "opesupo1@test.com", "PASSWORD": "password"}, "ClientId": "6h3if11rdlftv78gmboefijgk8"}', 'url': 'https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f955cdb50d0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': 'none'}}

2022-01-12T00:50:55.433+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,432 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Making request for OperationModel(name=InitiateAuth) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'X-Amz-Target': 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55'}, 'body': b'{"AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH", "AuthParameters": {"USERNAME": "opesupo1@test.com", "PASSWORD": "password"}, "ClientId": "6h3if11rdlftv78gmboefijgk8"}', 'url': 'https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'ap-northeast-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f955cdb50d0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': 'none'}}

2022-01-12T00:50:55.433+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.432Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443

2022-01-12T00:50:55.433+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,432 urllib3.connectionpool [DEBUG] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): codeguru-profiler.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443

2022-01-12T00:50:55.433+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.433Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event request-created.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f955cdb51c0>>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.433+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,433 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event request-created.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f955cdb51c0>>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.434+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.434Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Event choose-signer.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f955cead430>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.434+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,434 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event choose-signer.cognito-identity-provider.InitiateAuth: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f955cead430>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.434+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.434Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'X-Amz-Target': b'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth', 'Content-Type': b'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55', 'Content-Length': '153'}>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.434+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,434 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'X-Amz-Target': b'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth', 'Content-Type': b'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.18.55 Python/3.9.8 Linux/4.14.252-207.481.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_python3.9 Botocore/1.21.55', 'Content-Length': '153'}>

2022-01-12T00:50:55.435+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.435Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Certificate path: /var/runtime/botocore/cacert.pem

2022-01-12T00:50:55.435+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,435 botocore.httpsession [DEBUG] Certificate path: /var/runtime/botocore/cacert.pem

2022-01-12T00:50:55.436+09:00   2022-01-11 15:50:55,436 urllib3.connectionpool [DEBUG] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443

2022-01-12T00:50:55.436+09:00   [DEBUG] 2022-01-11T15:50:55.436Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443

2022-01-12T00:51:00.398+09:00   END RequestId: a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798

2022-01-12T00:51:00.398+09:00   REPORT RequestId: a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Duration: 5506.60 ms Billed Duration: 5000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB Init Duration: 490.72 ms XRAY TraceId: 1-61dda75e-232fd59e22db005744701ec9 SegmentId: 5ad1e3777e572f65 Sampled: true

2022-01-12T00:51:00.398+09:00   2022-01-11T15:51:00.398Z a809239e-e99a-47e1-8e72-eb27645a0798 Task timed out after 5.51 seconds
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you initializing boto3 client/resource inside lambda handler or outside?

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured for multiple VPC subnets? If so, review the network routing for all of those subnets.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad Yes, inside lambda handler.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, but it works successfully a few times and then appears to be blocked. So, I doubt it is related to any network configuration issues! What do you think?

Comment: Why do you doubt that is the cause? I’m not saying it is for certain, but those are exactly the symptoms of multiple configured subnets and one or more subnet routings being wrong. Specifically, if the Lambda first runs in a subnet with correct routing, it will work correctly because it can reach the remote services. Any subsequent warm start of that Lambda will be in the same subnet so will also work. However, at some point the Lambda will cold start and it may be in a different subnet, one whose routing is incorrect so it cannot reach the remote services and so it will time out.

Comment: You should try moving your boto3 session and database connections outside of the lambda handler so they are reused across lambda invocations.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for your explanation. I wasn't able to understand the relation with subnets earlier. Now I think you might have a point. I will try to set my Lambda only in the subnets that have access to Cognito for certain and will report back here. Thank you for bearing with me. :)